# Disable anchors in Chrome/WebKit/Safari

Tags: jquery, html, safari, google-chrome, webkit

Consider the following code:

```
$("a").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

In IE and FF, this will make anchors unclickable, but in WebKit based browsers (Google Chrome and Safari) this does nothing. The nice thing about the disabled attribute is that it is easily removed and does not effect the href and onclick attributes.

Do you have any suggestions on how to get the desired result. Answers must be:

- Easily be revertable, since I want to disable form input controls while I have an AJAX call running.
- Must work in IE, FF, and WebKit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you have an onclick event handler bound to these anchor elements. Just have your event handler check the "disabled" attribute and cancel the event if it is set. Your event handler would look something like this:

```
$("a").click(function(event){
  if (this.disabled) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    // make your AJAX call or whatever else you want
  }
});
```

You can also set a stylesheet rule to change the cursor.

```
a[disabled=disabled] { cursor: wait; }
```

Edit - simplified the "disabled" check as suggested in comments.

Comment: function diableForms() {
            $("input, button, textarea, a").attr("disabled", "disabled").css("cursor", "wait");
            
        }
        function enableForms() {
            $("input, button, textarea, a").not(".disabled").removeAttr("disabled").css("cursor", "");
        }

Comment: I just pasted the disableForms and enableForms functions I am using. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: if(this.disabled == "disabled") will be quicker

Comment: actually I think it's if(this.disabled) - i really should check my comments before i write them

Comment: if(this.disabled) is what I used. I don't have enough karma to edit posts or I would add some of this too Neall's post

Answer (score 2):

I had to fix this behavior in a site with a lot of anchors that were being enabled/disabled with this attribute according to other conditions, etc. Maybe not ideal, but in a situation like that, if you prefer not to fix each anchor's code individually, this will do the trick for all the anchors:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).attr('disabled')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    });
    var events = $._data ? $._data(this, 'events') : $(this).data('events');
    events.click.splice(0, 0, events.click.pop());
});
```

And:

```
a[disabled] {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Wow. This is fantastic, and should be marked as THE answer! How did this have zero upvotes?! I had started to actually modify the current answer to do what you are doing, having not initially read the 0 upvote answer! But why isn't your css selector a[disabled=disabled], and why not use the same selector in your jQuery.

Comment: took me a minute to decipher the splice + pop line. Clever. I like how it, in effect, deletes the last element while at the same time adding it to the front of the 'stack'.